# GNU make: What does '*** missing separator. Stop' mean for a source code file?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm fairly new to Makefiles, and I am trying to create one for a C project I am building using `gcc`.

I am familiar with the error `Makefile:<col>: *** missing separator. Stop.` It has popped up before when I used spaces instead of tabs to precede rules in the Makefile. I just tried writing a Makefile for this particular project (being sure to use TAB character instead of spaces) and when I run the `make` command, I get a very nondescript error I do not understand how to fix: `src/main.c:7: *** missing separator. Stop`

My directory structure looks like this:

```
- projectfolder/
    - Makefile
    - bin/
    - build/
    - inc/
    - src/
        - main.c
- otherfolder/
    - inc/
        - common.h
        - io.h
    - src/
        - io.c
```

`main.c`, which includes the `main` function, has the following imports:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "common.h"
#include "io.h"
```

My goal is to make a bunch of `.o` and `.d` files from the files in both `src/` and `inc/` directories and put those into `projectfolder/build/`, so that they can then be used to make the final executable in `projectfolder/bin/`

Finally, here is the Makefile that is causing the issue:

```
# Compiler and linker
CC          :=  gcc

# Target binary
TARGET      :=  the-program

# File extensions
SRCEXT      :=  c

# Directories
TARGETDIR   :=  bin
BUILDDIR    :=  build
SRCDIRS     :=  src /home/myusername/otherfolder/src
INCDIRS     :=  inc /home/myusername/otherfolder/inc

# gcc options
CCFLAGS     :=  -Wall -Wextra -O3

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
vpath   %.$(SRCEXT) $(SRCDIRS)
vpath   %.h         $(INCDIRS)
CCFLAGS +=  $(addprefix -I,$(INCDIRS)) -MMD -MP

SRC     :=  $(shell find $(SRCDIRS) -name *.$(SRCEXT))
OBJ     :=  $(SRC:$(SRCDIRS)/%.$(SRCEXT)=$(BUILDDIR)/%.o)
DEP     :=  $(OBJ:.o=.d)
TARGET  :=  $(TARGETDIR)/$(TARGET)

# RULE: Default make
all: makedirs $(TARGET) clean

# RULE: Remake
remake: fullclean all

# RULE: Clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILDDIR)

# RULE: Full clean (objects and binaries)
fullclean: clean
    rm -rf $(TARGETDIR)

# RULE: Make dirs
makedirs:
    mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)
    mkdir -p $(TARGETDIR)

# RULE: Link
$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(OBJ) -o $@

# RULE: Compile
$(OBJ): $(SRC)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# RULE: Non-file targets
.PHONY: all remake clean fullclean makedirs

# include dependencies
-include $(DEP)
```

What about this file would cause the described error? I am assuming that it is related to the Makefile itself rather than the C code actually contained in `src/main.c` since this does not appear to be a compilation error, but if I am wrong, let me know and I can change the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error:

```
src/main.c:7: *** missing separator. Stop
```

is clearly being printed by make.  Since we know the format of these messages is `<makefile>:<linenumber>: <error>`, we can see that make is trying to parse the file `src/main.c` as a makefile and obviously this cannot work.

How could make be doing such a thing?  The obvious culprit is this line:

```
-include $(DEP)
```

If the variable `DEP` contains the file `src/main.c`, then make would try to include that as a makefile and parse it.  So how is `DEP` set?

```
DEP     :=  $(OBJ:.o=.d)
```

This changes all words in `OBJ` that end with `.o` to end with `.d`.  Crucially, it should be noted that this makes no changes to words that *do not* end in `.o`.  So, if `OBJS` contained `src/main.c`, this would pass it through unmodified to `DEPS`.

So how is `OBJ` set?  Here are the relevant variables:

```
SRCDIRS     :=  src /home/myusername/otherfolder/src

SRC     :=  $(shell find $(SRCDIRS) -name *.$(SRCEXT))
OBJ     :=  $(SRC:$(SRCDIRS)/%.$(SRCEXT)=$(BUILDDIR)/%.o)
```

Let's expand this: the `SRC` variable runs:

```
find src /home/myusername/otherfolder/src -name *.c
```

(you really should escape the `*`, either with backslash or quotes: it's very dangerous how you have this).

Now we'll say that SRC gets the value:

```
SRC := src/main.c /home/myusername/otherfolder/src/other.c
```

Now what does `OBJ` contain?

```
OBJ     :=  $(SRC:src /home/myusername/otherfolder/src/%.$(SRCEXT)=build/%.o)
```

This clearly cannot work: you can't put multiple directories into `SRCDIRS`, but then treat it as if it contained only one word.

Comment: Thanks! To list multiple directories like that, I should instead use `foreach` over SRCDIRS to generate SRC, correct?

Comment: Before we can answer that we have to understand what your goal is.  Do you want all the object files to appear in `build` directly?  If so, what if you find two different source files with the same name (say `main.c`) but in different source directories?  Or do you want the object files to appear under `build`, but with their directory intact?  So, for example, `build/src/main.o`?  My suspicion is that you will have a simpler time taking advantage of `VPATH`, but you CAN do it with `foreach`.

Comment: thanks, ill look more at vpath next and see if I can get it working

Comment: @OhFiveight I included a link to a nice page detailing the use of VPATH in my answer.

Comment: @Vroomfondel I appreciate that, currently using the link!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the line

```
OBJ     :=  $(SRC:$(SRCDIRS)/%.$(SRCEXT)=$(BUILDDIR)/%.o)
```

The pattern substitution works *only* where the pattern matches and *leaves all other strings alone*.

As a simple demonstration see this makefile (no rules, just variable assignments):

```
x := foo bar baz
y := $(x:ba%=gu%)
$(info $(x))
$(info $(y))
```

Output:

```
foo bar baz
foo gur guz
```

As you can see, `foo` still is there, unchanged although it didn't match the pattern `ba%`.

In your case you are passing an impossible to substitute pattern, the content of `$(SRCDIRS)`, which is the two words: `src /home/myusername/otherfolder/src` to the substitution call, therefore `main.c` - which is either `src/main.c` or `/home/myusername/otherfolder/src/main.c`  remains unchanged in your list, gets inadvertently flushed further into `$(DEP)` and is finally included as text with your last line `-include $(DEP)`.

As a recommendation I want to point you to `VPATH` (see manual and here: https://www.cmcrossroads.com/article/basics-vpath-and-vpath), which is the better alternative to indicate the location of your sources to `make`.